# Bluetooth Adapter not found in Debian buster

Tags: drivers, bluetooth

After a fresh install, my bluetooth adapters are missing in Debian Buster.

[image]

Here are few outputs from several console commands to help you to help me.

```
$ sudo lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM75 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
```

---

```
$ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# show
No default controller available
[bluetooth]# scan on
No default controller available
[bluetooth]# devices
No default controller available
[bluetooth]#
```

---

```
$ lsmod | grep blue
bluetooth             647168  12 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,ath3k,btusb
ecdh_generic           24576  1 bluetooth
rfkill                 28672  9 bluetooth,cfg80211
crc16                  16384  2 bluetooth,ext4
```

---

```
$ sudo hcitool dev
Devices:
```

Edit:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0cf3:3004 Qualcomm Atheros Communications AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 002 Device 086: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy series, misc. (MTP mode)
Bus 002 Device 092: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy series, misc. (MTP mode)
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2232:1029 Silicon Motion WebCam SC-13HDL11939N
Bus 001 Device 042: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

---

```
$ sudo dmesg -H
[Dec27 01:49] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/all, error -71
[  +0.087578] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 86 using ehci-pci
[  +0.091997] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  +0.220904] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6860, bcdDevice= 4.00
[  +0.000007] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[  +0.000003] usb 2-1.2: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
[  +0.000003] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
[  +0.000003] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 31006a60bc916300
[  +0.001675] cdc_acm 2-1.2:1.1: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[  +9.751237] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 86
[  +0.002457] cdc_acm 2-1.2:1.1: failed to set dtr/rts
[  +0.255609] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 87 using ehci-pci
[  +0.109766] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6860, bcdDevice= 4.00
[  +0.000014] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[  +0.000006] usb 2-1.2: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
[  +0.000004] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
[  +0.000005] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 31006a60bc916300
[  +0.003301] cdc_acm 2-1.2:1.1: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[  +4.236783] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 87
[  +0.002069] cdc_acm 2-1.2:1.1: failed to set dtr/rts
[  +0.268010] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 88 using ehci-pci
[  +0.091980] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[Dec27 01:55] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 89 using ehci-pci
[  +0.109939] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6860, bcdDevice= 4.00
[  +0.000013] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[  +0.000006] usb 2-1.2: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
[  +0.000005] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
[  +0.000004] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 31006a60bc916300
:
```

If you need output of any certain command, let me know in comments.

Comment: thanks for the edit.

Comment: The only radio device in your `lspci` output is Qualcomm Atheros AR9485, and according to its datasheet it is a pure Wi-Fi device: it has no Bluetooth functionality built in. Please show the `sudo lsusb` output also: a Bluetooth transceiver is usually implemented as an USB device, since it doesn't require as high a bandwidth as Wi-Fi.

Comment: @telcoM Hi, I pasted the output in the edit.

Answer (score 3):

Your Bluetooth chip is Qualcomm Atheros AR3012, which is driven by the `ath3k.ko` kernel module. Your `lsmod` output indicates that module is actually loaded.

But that module will also need a firmware file `/lib/firmware/ath3k-1.fw`, which comes in package `firmware-atheros`. That package is in the `non-free` section of the Debian package repository. Install it if you haven't already done so. If you don't see `firmware-atheros` as an available package in your favorite package management tool, you may need to enable the non-free repository section first.

(Note: "non-free" here means "no source code available, hence not fully Free Software". It does not mean you would need to pay for it.)

To enable the non-free repository, edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file as root. You'll see a line similar to this:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
```

Just add the `non-free` keyword at the end:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main non-free
```

Then run `apt update` as root, and try your favorite package management utility again. Now the `firmware-atheros` package should be installable.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I tried what you suggested and ran `$ sudo apt-get install firmware-atheros` and one of lines of the output said `firmware-atheros is already the newest version (20190114-2).` followed by `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: So that wasn't the problem either. After booting the system, run `sudo dmesg -H` and look for any lines mentioning "bluetooth" or "ath3k". Is there anything that looks like an error message? [Looks like Atheros has used the same USB device ID for two Bluetooth chips requiring different drivers, making identification of the correct driver problematic.](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-bluetooth/msg66419.html)

Comment: I made an edit again

Comment: That `dmesg -H` seems to be only about connecting and disconnecting a Samsung Galacy series phone. Nothing Bluetooth-related in there.