# Bluetooth: No Adapters Found on Debian 10 buster

Tags: debian, bluetooth

I have a dual booted laptop with built it bluetooth. which works for windows 8.1 but not in Debian 10. I have seen some other questions related to the problem, and I assume I need to install some drivers. The thing is I don't know which drivers and how to install them on Debian.

Ran `rfkill list` on the Konsole after seeing some of the answers, got command not known.

Comment: The Debian wiki has a [page for users of Bluetooth](https://wiki.debian.org/BluetoothUser).

Comment: @berndbausch _"We assume you have a Bluetooth adapter in your computer and a Bluetooth device (such as a mobile phone or PDA)."_   
I dont have an adapter.

Comment: Without a Bluetooth adapter, you can't use Bluetooth. Note that the sentence says "**in** your computer".

Comment: According to your question, there is an adapter built into your laptop? What does the datasheet from the manufacturer say about the existence of Bluetooth?

Comment: @Ned64 The Bluetooth is builtin with adapters, I mistook Drivers for Adapters since the error message said no Adapter Found, I had to install some non free drivers to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing was I needed to install some non free software hence another solution on this website worked for me https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/559147/456418

Answer (score 0):

Replace the Debian 10 not working BT card, by one of the follow state of art 10 to 30 USD, BT5.1 and WIFI 6 cards:

- Intel AX200
- Devi AX3000 (use the same chips like intel AX200, and make it usable for the old Intel called "HMW" slot)