# Bluetooth devices not found in Debian 11

Tags: debian, dual-boot, bluetooth

I have dual boot Win10-Debian11, Lenovo Yoga slim 7 pro. In the Windows system Bluetooth devices are successfully found, but in the Debian I can't see any.

I've turned off bluetooth in win system and following the instructions from wiki.debian  installed `bluez-firmware` package.
`systemctl status bluetooth.service` gives me the following:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-11-28 07:35:25 CET; 4min 44s ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 1473 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 16547)
     Memory: 2.1M
        CPU: 24ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─1473 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd --noplugin=sap

Nov 28 07:35:25 debian systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Nov 28 07:35:25 debian bluetoothd[1473]: Bluetooth daemon 5.55
Nov 28 07:35:25 debian systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Nov 28 07:35:25 debian bluetoothd[1473]: Starting SDP server
Nov 28 07:35:25 debian bluetoothd[1473]: Excluding (cli) sap
Nov 28 07:35:25 debian bluetoothd[1473]: Bluetooth management interface 1.18 initialized
Nov 28 07:35:25 debian bluetoothd[1473]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
Nov 28 07:35:25 debian bluetoothd[1473]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.35 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Nov 28 07:35:25 debian bluetoothd[1473]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.35 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Nov 28 07:35:27 debian bluetoothd[1473]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
```

after

```
#rfkill unblock bluetooth
#systemctl restart bluetooth
#rmmod btusb
```

the error "failed to set mode..." disappeared, but I still don't see any bluetooth devices. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The following comment helped me a lot:
[Bluetooth Adapter not found in Debian buster](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/559134/bluetooth-adapter-not-found-in-debian-buster)

Sometime is necessary we know the brand of hardware and search the driver.
I knew the brand with the next command:

```
$ lsusb
```

And I searched drivers.